# Comparing multidimensional lists and return the intersected index

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-mining, nested-lists

I try to write and edit a code based on some example from the [internet](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/) that goes like this:

```
from math import sqrt

# calculate the Euclidean distance between two vectors
def euclidean_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(row1)-1):
        distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
    return sqrt(distance)

# Locate the clostest neighbors
def get_neighbors(train, test_row, num_neighbors):
    distances = list()
    for train_row in train:
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_row, train_row)
        distances.append((train_row, dist))
    distances.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    neighbors = list()
    for i in range(num_neighbors):
        neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
    return neighbors

# Test distance function
dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0],
    [1.465489372,2.362125076,0],
    [3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
    [1.38807019,1.850220317,0],
    [3.06407232,3.005305973,0],
    [7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
    [5.332441248,2.088626775,1],
    [6.922596716,1.77106367,1],
    [8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
    [7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]
neighbors = get_neighbors(dataset, dataset[0], 3)

#set(dataset) & set(neighbors)

#type(neighbors) is int
#set(dataset).intersection(neighbors)

for neighbor in neighbors:
    print(neighbor)
```

What I want to do is:

1. Getting the 3 nearest neighbors,
2. Comparing those  nearest neighbors to the 'dataset',
3. Return the index of data point that matches.

For example:
from the code above, the result is:

```
[2.7810836, 2.550537003, 0]
[3.06407232, 3.005305973, 0]
[1.465489372, 2.362125076, 0]
```

The end result that I would like to have is:

result = [1, 5, 2]

which is the dataset index of the nearest 3 neighbors from the selected data point (including itself) assuming that the data index is starting from 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is that you return the rows themselves from your get neighbours function. To solve this, change the line:

```
neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
```

to

```
neighbors.append(train.index(distances[i][0]) + 1)
```

which finds the index of the row in the full list of rows, and increments by one as you want the indexes to start at one.

The result is now

```
[1, 5, 2]
```